# Fast evaluation of quadratic matrix product when changed slightly

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I know that $x^T A x = b$, where $x$ is a vector with $x_i\in\{0,1\}$, $A$ is square with real numbers as elements.

Now suppose I flip two of the "bits" of $x$ i.e. change one of $x_i$ from $0$ to $1$ and another $x_i$ from $1$ to $0$.
Is there a fast way of calculating (for very large sized $A$) the new matrix product $x^{*T}Ax^*=c$ using the previous result?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the result of $y^TAy$, where $y$ (your $x^*$) is a vector such that $y-x$ has exactly two non-zero entries (one of which is $1$ and the other $-1$).

The value of $x^TAx$ alone isn't really enough information to do anything useful, but if you also stored the result $(A + A^T)x$, then you could use the following fact. Let $\delta = y-x$. We have
$$
y^TAy = (x+\delta)^TA(x + \delta) = x^TAx + [Ax + A^Tx]^T\delta + \delta^TA\delta.
$$
Because $\delta$ is sparse, the products $[(A + A^T)x]^T\delta$ and $\delta^TA\delta$ can be quickly computed (in particular by adding/subtracting 6 values).